# Flash ActionScript Slot Machine PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

I have created 2 slot machines 
1st is entirely out of flash:
 second is nearly complete using php for all odds and calculations, pay outs ect,flash is only visual in this version not as much script only to show what icons and animations on which payline so far its a 15 line video slot ...
My question is?

Is it better to have the slot machine with php as the back end, or using actionSCript is fine...
I cant Find much information on this but basically i want to know if i am wasting my time with php worried about security when flash is secure? im not sure which i should keep going with.

Comment: I would not say Flash is secure. Anything on the front-end is automatically less secure than the back-end.

Comment: would you think php could be acceptable?

Comment: Yes.  Please make sure you use proper sanity checks and ensure that you use precaution when working with backend databases (use parametrized queries, salt hashes with user passwords, NEVER NEVER NEVER store credit card #s in the clear, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's about real money you must not rely on flash for security. Server side checking is required :) It is trivial to memory hack flash, send faked data (if anything at all is sent), proxy override the swf with your own etc.

Comment: fair enough i will stick with php, wasnt sure what the online casino use, could be java i got no idea.... if you have an idea im happy to hear it, im clueless

Comment: PHP should be fine. Use whatever you are comfortable with. But whatever you do, don't trust the client with anything.